# Proving $(A\times C)\cup(B\times D)\subseteq(A\cup B)\times(C\cup D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been trying to prove the following for a while now, but I can't get to the solution:

$$(A\times C)\cup(B\times D)\subseteq(A\cup B)\times(C\cup D)$$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? There are a number of ways to do a proof of $P\subseteq Q$, but generally the simplest are to either show that 1) $x\in P \Rightarrow x \in Q$ or 2) $\exists x: x \in P \wedge x \notin Q \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$.

Comment: Take a point $(x,y)\in (A\times C)\cup(B\times D)$ and show that $(x,y)\in (A\cup B)\times (C\cup D)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y)\in (A\times C)\cup (B\times D)$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, and $y\in C$ or $y\in D$. Indeed, then $x\in A\cup B, y\in C\cup D$. So, $(x,y)\in (A\cup B)\times (C\cup D)$. This implies that 
$$ (A\times C)\cup (B\times D)\subseteq (A\cup B)\times (C\cup D). $$

Comment: How did you manage to come from this situation: (x∈A and y∈C) or (x∈B and y∈D)

Comment: What do you mean by "come from" exactly?

Comment: I mean how to continue further.

Comment: Well, we have $(x,y)$ and we should think about each "coordinate" separately. You can try to think about $A\times C$ and $B\times D$ like unit intervals in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For instance, $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $[1,2]\times[1,2]$. Draw this picture and I hope it will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have:

$$(A\cup B)\times (C\cup D)= (A\times C)\cup (A\times D)\cup(B\times C)\cup (B\times D)$$